# How to iterate an object with a specific key in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to list an item inside a specific key using a filter. Now listing like this.

- Sanal
- Jin
- John
- Tim
- Jeff
- Sam
- John
- Tim

I want like this using a filter

- Jeff
- Sam

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vimalv86/2tpb3/47/)

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = {"id":"B716","day":8,"di":{"type":"normal","one":[{"name":"Sanal","age":"18"},{"name":"Jin","age":"25"}],"two":[{"name":"Jeff","age":"55"},{"name":"Sam","age":"32"}],"three":[{"name":"John","age":"34"},{"name":"Tim","age":"39"}]}};
}
```

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="val in items.di">
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="value in val">{{value.name}}</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you indent the object, you should be able to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your ng repeat change it as

```
<li ng-repeat="value in val | filter: val.name='jeff'">{{value.name}}</li>
```

I have used name you can use the value that you want ot test

Comment: I want to display with the key. (here 'two')

Comment: @Vimal - With what key?  what is 'two'?  having a hard time trying to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Rani - Currently in the fiddle I am listing the names form the array (one, two and three). But i want to list the names only from one array.